# What filter button whit jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery:

```
 $(".utente1").click(function () {

            $('.newdiv').hide();

$('.hidecolor').find('.vc_single_image-img').css('filter','grayscale(100%)');

            $(".utente-1").show(600);   

      $('.utente1').find('.img').css('filter','none')
    })
```

When I click the other button, the button utente1 remaning filter:none

When I click .utente1 it opens the div, but I would like the button(.utente1) to change color also.

Comment: Please put the full HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Add this code inside utente1 click :

```
$(this).css('color','red');
```

so your full code will be :

```
$(".utente1").click(function () {
        $('.newdiv').hide();
        $(".utente-1").show(600);  
        $(this).css('color','red');
 });
```

if you want to change the color of all the buttons. add one comman class for those buttons and then set the css :

```
 $(".utente1").click(function () {
            $('.newdiv').hide();
            $(".utente-1").show(600);  
            $(".commanClass").css('color','red');
     });
```

Comment: ok sorry but i have insert color filter .. for example filter:grayscale(100%);

Comment: i resolved   $('.utente-1-').find('.img').css('filter','none')